# Does "watered up" mean you have a craving for something?

Tags: phrase-usage, colloquialisms

Tonight at dinner my friend from Tulsa, OK read from the menu that the university cafeteria was serving egg noodles at one of the stations. To his disappointment, they were actually serving rice.

"That's too bad," he said. "I was really *watered up* for those noodles."

I stopped him and asked about his usage of the phrase "watered up." Apparently, his family uses it to describe a craving one has for something. I had never heard it before, so I started asking people around the cafe and no one else had either.

Has anyone else heard the phrase used so?

Comment: Not in that context: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="watered+up"

Comment: @Greybeard - [consider ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=watered+up%2Csalivating%2Cchamping+at&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @stevesliva: Yes, I did do: From the examples in Google Booke -- *plants watered up to 100% of soil field capacity* -- *the way his eyes watered up for a second.* -- *Stomach queasy, eyes watered up, Mary almost knocked down her uncle,* -- *With everyone hayed up, watered up and rugged up, we clambered back into the trailer* - I still haven't heard it in that context...

Comment: I made two comments yesterday, and both are construed as disagreement when I mean them more as constructive asides.  For ngram, I personally like the metrics about relative use whenever anyone talks about how idiomatic something is.   The examples in the answers make it sound like regional vernacular.  Ngram supports that, even if it catches some examples of the phrase that might be from other meanings.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to find some other examples online, which indicates that this expression is used all across America (though I've never personally heard it). It's clearly referring to things that are mouth-watering.

[Fancy Little Things](https://fancylittlethings.com/2014/09/pumpkin-paleo-style/) (Virginia, USA):

> I’ve noticed many of my friends on social media beginning to post pumpkin donuts and pumpkin spiced latte’s. They get me watered up for some, but I have to look up recipes, gather ingredients, and get time to make them from scratch.

[Dinner on the U.S.S. Lexington](https://www.twtex.com/forums/threads/dinner-on-the-u-s-s-lexington.28066/) (Texas, USA):

> I was just enjoying the ride along the coast, and was all watered up for fresh seafood; I didn't care what town or restaurant it came from.

[Brooke Town](https://www.facebook.com/groverbeachsourdough/posts/lots-of-delicious-options-at-295-west-grand-ave-we-have-our-bakery-and-our-new-a/1291732024506698/) (California, USA):

> Get watered up for Avocado Toast, Benedict, Ramen, Meatloaf, Tartare, Salad, Soup, Handmade Pasta, Bologna, Fried Chicken & so much more.

[Nick B.](https://www.yelp.com/biz/kellys-cajun-grill-nashville?q=watered%20up) (Tennessee, USA):

> I was all watered up for some jambalaya, crawfish pie, and file gumbo.

Comment: I always thought this came from something like 'my mouth got all watered up when I saw that menu'. Do you have any idea as to its origin?

Comment: @Heartspring.  Seems to conjur same as *salivating*.

Answer (score 1):

As the examples in Laurel's answer suggest, the relevant phrase in the context of food (or other) craving is not simply "watered up" but "watered up for." Several fairly early instances of "watered up for" in Google Books search results make the connection to "mouth watering" explicit.

From Mildred Taylor, [*Let the Circle Be Unbroken*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zfUcAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&dq=%22watered+up+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM99Srrp6BAxUEIzQIHQ2GBcoQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22watered%20up%20for%22&f=false) (1991):

> Uncle Hammer put an arm around Big Ma. "Mama, now I know y'all done had breakfast a long time ago and dinner's still a good couple of hours away, but I tell you what **my mouth's really watered up for**, and that's some of them fine biscuits of yours, some oil sausages, and some clabber milk and some good ole cane syrup. Think I could bother you for some?"

From Catherine Hart, [*Irresistible*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oZPs33-oOUEC&q=%22watered+up+for%22&dq=%22watered+up+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfk-G2sJ6BAxW_O0QIHTUbCsAQ6AF6BAgGEAI) (1994) [snippet view]:

> Jade gave an inelegant snort. "Come on, Lizette," she told her friend."It won't do ye any good to get **yer mouth all watered up for that one**. He's a preacher with a wagon full o' orphans. B'sides that, he don't cotton to trollops, and he doesn't want his wee charges exposed to us."

And from Rachel Vogelsang, [*Racheltracks*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NsoeSAJXCKgC&pg=PA170&dq=%22watered+up+for%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfk-G2sJ6BAxW_O0QIHTUbCsAQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22watered%20up%20for%22&f=false) (1999):

> After this generous soul, and flushed with the first rewards of success, we decided to try for four hundred lire so we could buy milk and make biscuits. We thought of pancakes, for I have an old jar of maple syrup, but we had no eggs. Flour, baking powder and salt we did have so **our mouths watered up for homemade biscuits**.

Google Book doesn't report any matches for the expression from earlier than 1991. Nevertheless, the expression seems to be at least a hundred years old, to judge from this instance from J.D. Aldredge, [*The Romance of Growing a Boy in Texas: Autobiographical Sketches of His Early Life as a Boy*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=txa.ark%3A%2F81423%2Fd2rp47&seq=79&q1=%22watered+up+for%22), volume 1 (1923), uncovered in a Hathitrust search:

> It was about the first of July, and the "water was fine", but we were enjoying the anticipation of that melon "feast" more than the water.
>
> **Our mouths were **"watered up" for** its red juicy? meat**. But we were to have some other experiences first. For we looked up over the embankment of the "creek" and up the hill, and "behold"! if there didn't appear, my brother Dawson.

Aldredge was the pastor of Central Baptist Church in Jacksonville, Texas—a small town (in 1923) in East Texas about equidistant from Dallas and Shreveport, Louisiana.

Of the other examples noted in this answer. Taylor's is set in Mississippi and Vogelsang's is in Italy although the narrator says that her mother lives in Georgia. Hart's book appears to be about a pioneer journey west from Richmond, Virginia,although it is unclear where the character who uses the expression is from. These various examples point to usage across the U.S. South, which would be consistent with its having some currency in Oklahoma as well.